# How to get savedUri after capture video in CameraX?

Tags: java, android, androidx, video-capture, android-camerax

I want to get uri from CaptureVideo of CameraX

Here is my code for capture video

```
private void takeVideo() {
    if (mso != null) {
        if (recording != null) {
            recording.close();
            recording = null;
            return;
        }
        recording = videoCapture.getOutput().prepareRecording(CameraActivity.this, mso)
                .start(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), new Consumer<VideoRecordEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(VideoRecordEvent videoRecordEvent) {
                        if (videoRecordEvent instanceof VideoRecordEvent.Start) {
                            setBackgroundBtn(R.drawable.recoding);
                            Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "recoding start...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (videoRecordEvent instanceof VideoRecordEvent.Finalize) {
                            setBackgroundBtn(R.drawable.round_bg);
                            Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Recoding stop ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

The uri should return somewhere on event `VideoRecordEvent.Finalize`
I debugged recording and show uri when trigger `VideoRecordEvent.Finalize` and the uri is in `recoding.mRecorder.mOutputUri.uriString`

But I have no idea how to get this value because no function to get that uri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer, I use `getOutputResults().getOutputUri()`

```
recording = videoCapture.getOutput().prepareRecording(CameraActivity.this, mso)
                .start(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), new Consumer<VideoRecordEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(VideoRecordEvent videoRecordEvent) {
                        if (videoRecordEvent instanceof VideoRecordEvent.Start) {
                            // do something
                        } else if (videoRecordEvent instanceof VideoRecordEvent.Finalize) {
                            ...
                            Uri result = ((VideoRecordEvent.Finalize) videoRecordEvent).getOutputResults().getOutputUri();
                            Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "result url: " + result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Recoding stop ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Or `recordEvent.outputResults.outputUri` [CameraX Codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#6) on event finalize

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is check if recording is not null, then it means that the video recording was successfully started. Then the `outputFileOptions` from the recording object that is the one that contains the `URI` you are looking for. Then to get the `Uri` you need to cast the `outputFileOptions` to `OutputFileUriOptions` and retrieve the `URI` using the `getUri()` method, then if you want it as `String` you have to add the `toString()` to it.

```
@Override
public void accept(VideoRecordEvent videoRecordEvent) {
    if (videoRecordEvent instanceof VideoRecordEvent.Start) {
        setBackgroundBtn(R.drawable.recoding);
        Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "recording start...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (videoRecordEvent instanceof VideoRecordEvent.Finalize) {
        setBackgroundBtn(R.drawable.round_bg);
        Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Recording stop ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (recording != null) {
            OutputFileOptions outputFileOptions = recording.getOutputFileOptions();
            if (outputFileOptions instanceof OutputFileOptions.OutputFileUriOptions) {
                Uri outputFileUri = ((OutputFileOptions.OutputFileUriOptions) outputFileOptions).getUri();
                String outputFileUriString = outputFileUri.toString();
                Log.d("CameraX", "Video output URI: " + outputFileUriString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: recording doesn't have method `getOutputFileOptions()`